# Get a wrong number of rows while using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d=pd.read_csv('data.csv',usecols=['time','velocity','dis'])
```

This code gives me the wrong number of rows, lager than the rows in the original csv file, my csv file is complicated, it has a column of the whole string, and a column of empty, and a column of numbers, I know this could be a bad question, but it has 1 milion rows, I cannot find which part is wrong,so what I should try?

Comment: If the strings have embedded newlines, which is allowed, then the number of "rows" is less than the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand, my rows more than the file.

Comment: you will have to write program which compare both - file and dataframe - to see which rows makes problem.